# Unable to open github.com Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: ubuntu, github

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with a wired connection. For the last 7 days, I have been unable to open [Github](https://github.com). It instead has an error.

Is there anything wrong with my connection / hardware / network / browser settings or in website itself?

Chrome gives **This webpage is not available** with below details

> The server at github.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Chromium
>   from accessing the network. Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Firefox gives **Server not found**

P.S. no firewall software installed on my system.

Comment: I can get to the site using chrome. It has to be a DNS issue possibly with your ISP. You can test by changing your client computer DNS to the Google public DNS server 8.8.8.8. Make a note of what your current DNS setting are before changing. If you have a firewall (there can be one in any DSL or Cable modem), you may have to change any DNS settings there too. Test without changing the firewall first. If you can get to github using Google's DNS, then you know that your previous DNS servers settings were not working and you will need to call your ISP if you were using their DNS servers.

Comment: @closetnoc I am unable to change DNS manually. it's an individual broadband wired connection and if tried to make any changes in DNS then have to configure IPv4 and gateway. which is not provided to me. :|

Comment: You will then need to talk to your ISP. It sounds like a DNS issue and it is possible that they are aware of some issues. Otherwise, they might appreciate your bringing it to their attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Open Network and Sharing center ->change Adapter setting->Your Network->rigth click
->TCP/Ipv 4->click on properties ->use the following DNS server addresses ->
Preffered DNS Server :9.9.9.9
Alternate DNS Server :9.9.8.8

Comment: Can you explain what the DNS servers are, who runs them, and why they work better?

Comment: Thanks. this works ..but in UBUNTU it's bit different .only need to write Additional DNS server to `8.8.8.8` without changing any other thing

Comment: i am using windows 7 and set DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and it works for me. thanks

Comment: I prefer 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 ([Cloudflare](https://1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com/dns/)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a different platform. I was using windows 8.1 when I suddenly could not access github anymore, this error came right after creating a site on github pages.

I solved this by flushing my dns cache.

Type this in the command promt:

ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: This won't help him in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu just: right click on your connection on panel (top right on unity by default) and click configure network connections. Then right click on your wifi -> click edit -> go to IPv4 (you may need to extend the window to see it), and in "Other DNS servers" type: `8.8.8.8,9.9.8.8` and click OK.[my settings on my Kubuntu (KDE instead of Unity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNrxI.png)